SB Admin setLengthMenu
I'm using CodeIgniter 4 and SB Admin for my admin dashboard, but I don't know how to set entries per page (rows) option for the datatable, so I can add 50, 100 and all.  According to Gemini I should set the setLengthMenu array, but I can't find the location. Could anybody help me ?
